# Two-term asymptotic approximation for roots of a polynomial (dominant balance)

Tags: polynomials, complex-numbers, asymptotics, roots

I'm trying to find the roots to the following equation:

$t^5 - \epsilon t^3 + \epsilon^3 = 0$

as $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$.

From expansion $t= \epsilon^{\alpha}t_1 + \epsilon^{2\alpha}t_2 + \mathcal{O}(\epsilon^{3\alpha})$ this gives me two of the roots:

$t= \epsilon^{1/2} -\frac{1}{2}\epsilon + \mathcal{O}(\epsilon^{3/2})$

$t= -\epsilon^{1/2} -\frac{1}{2}\epsilon + \mathcal{O}(\epsilon^{3/2})$

I can't find the other 3 roots. Can someone please help?

Comment: How many real roots do you expect to this equation? For positive $\epsilon$ there will be turning points at $0$ (where the value is positive) and $\pm \sqrt {\epsilon}$. At $+\sqrt {\epsilon}$ the polynomial will be positive at the turning point, so no zero there. Neglecting the term in $\epsilon^3$ you would expect roots near $\pm \sqrt {\epsilon}$ and three roots near $0$, but four of these will not be real roots.

Comment: no two of them are real, as I have shown. I'm trying to figure out the other 3

Comment: I'm afraid that you have not shown that the positive estimate of a root actually gives a real root. The "turning point" at zero is an inflexion.

Comment: please explain what you mean

Comment: all i have done is expanded $t(\epsilon)$ and equated powers. this gives me 2 real roots

Comment: But the function is positive near the positive estimate of a root with a positive local minimum - you haven't equated enough powers and have cut off the estimate too early. If you graph the function or compute it on a spreadsheet you will find that the positive value near your estimated root is very small.